# Is it actually advantageous to use const references for non-primitive function parameters when possible?

Tags: c++

As a matter of habit and when it's possible to do so, I always have function parameters use a const reference when its type is non-primitive, e.g.:

```
void myFunction(int a, const SomeStruct &b, const SomeClass &c)
{ ... }
```

The reasoning is that a const reference is trivial to pass to a function (since it's basically just an address) and guarantees that a struct isn't going to be copied or a class isn't going to be constructed.

But is that actually necessary? It strikes me that the compiler ought to be able to tell when it would be a valid optimization not to copy a class or struct, and just automatically make it a reference behind the scenes. And the constant use of `const &` increases the visual complexity of the code, so I could argue it improves readability *not* to use it.

Is this a needless micro-optimization or is it actually a good idea?

Comment: It's going to cause you to get an error if you call a non-const member function on that reference. If that's what you want, then it seems advantageous.

Comment: How does `const&` add to the visual complexity?  WWhen you start to do things like multithreading these optimizations might actually break code (refer to objects that go out of scope earlier then the thread ends) and a copy is required. Also don't forget C++ has to be backward compatible with billions of lines of code and these optimizations can only be done if it can be absoluletly guaranteed they will always be correct. (As was done with return value optimization). In any way for me "visual compexity" is mostly an indication you're still getting used to C++ ;)

Comment: _I always have function parameters use a  `const` reference when its type is non-primitive_ as opposed to what?  I mean, the answer to that question is implied, but not stated.

Comment: "It strikes me that the compiler ought to be able to tell when it would be a valid optimization not to copy a class or struct, and just automatically make it a reference behind the scenes" That's very much not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It strikes me that the compiler ought to be able to tell when it would be a valid optimization not to copy a class or struct, and just automatically make it a reference behind the scenes.

A compiler (probably) could tell this, but "automatically make it a reference behind the scenes" is more complicated than "just".

One factor that influences whether or not skipping a copy is valid is the function definition. If the function makes changes to the copy, then skipping the copy is not valid. However, the function definition is not necessarily known to the compiler at the call site. So the call sites don't necessarily know if a copy can be skipped.

So should the compiler treat all parameters as `const` references and let the function decide if a copy is needed? No, this would become a pessimism when the provided argument is a prvalue. A prvalue can be passed by value without making a copy, but if it goes through a `const` reference, then a copy would be needed. It is both the call site and the function definition that influence whether a copy is needed.

OK, so could the compiler provide wrappers for each function? One wrapper to accept by value and one to accept by `const` reference? One of these wrappers could be the "real" function, while the other forwards to it. It's only one additional wrapper for every function, right? Wrong, because functions can take multiple parameters, and the number of wrappers grows exponentially with the number of parameters. This is technically possible, but can cause needless executable bloat.

I'll skip the complication from factoring in function pointers, which would have to use the declared parameters to be valid. I'll just note that this would introduce inconsistencies in what is considered good practice, which can be far more cognitive overhead than a little visual complexity.

The result is a lot of work for the compiler, and a likely increase in executable size. The gain is small in practice since programmers have gotten used to the `const` reference rules of thumb. Also, this would not eliminate the need to use `const` references, since sometimes copying either has side-effects (hence cannot be skipped) or is not allowed.

So, I'd call it theoretically possible but unlikely in practice.

> Is this a needless micro-optimization or is it actually a good idea?

It is a micro-optimization and a good idea.

Note that this is a subtly different question than "ought to be able to". Asking if this is a good idea is asking if any compilers actually do this sort of processing, not merely if they are theoretically capable of it.

Comment: Your point about the compiler not necessarily having the function definition is a really good one, and one I hadn't thought of immediately. That alone is enough to justify not trying to do any compile time optimizations of what looks like passing by value.

Answer (score 2):

It’s not about code efficiency. It’s about the programmer knowing that the object cannot be modified.

Comment: I assume you refer to const. But passing by ref or value does matter for efficiency. And const ref can be safely replaced with const value (unlike non-const situation which changes meaning, because of updates visibility), which can be really beneficial if the struct is small enough.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the class you're passing around is not *copyable*. So that's when you will need a reference parameter (unless you choose to *move* it).

Also having `const` all over the place means you'll have less cognitive overload reading and understanding what gets mutated in the code.

It also helps the compiler further optimize the code in some rare cases.

With that said, small classes (e.g. <= 16 bytes) that are cheap to copy are better off being copied/moved (value semantics) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

struct Ridic {
  Ridic() {
    std::cout << "Default Ctor.\n";
  }

  Ridic(Ridic const& other) {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::cout << "Copy " << std::flush;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(10s);
    std::cout << "Ctor.\n";
  }

  void say() const {
    std::cout << "This is ridiculous.\n";
  }
};

void with_copy(Ridic r) {
  r.say();
}

void with_cref(Ridic const& r) {
  r.say();
}

int main() {
  Ridic r;

  with_cref(r);
  with_copy(r);
}
```

It's not unheard for large objects to be expensive to copy. If you can avoid that expense why wouldn't you?